# How to merge 2 different keys and combine their values as a list for JSON Object in python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object/python dictionary like this:

```
{  
"trip_id": 19121027,
"Latitude": "21.160284",
"Longitude": "72.772457",
"Speed": "46.00"
}
```

I want to combine the latitude and longitude parts as "Location" like:

```
{  
"trip_id": 19121027,
"Location":["21.160284","72.772457"],
"Speed": "46.00"
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want a new dictionary or do you want to modify the original?

Comment: i think either ways it'd be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
data1 = {  
"trip_id": 19121027,
"Latitude": "21.160284",
"Longitude": "72.772457",
"Speed": "46.00"
}

data2 = {
"trip_id": data1["trip_id"],
"Location": [data1["Latitude"], data1["Longitude"]],
"Speed": data1["Speed"]
}
```

Comment: This does answer the question but the technique is dubious. Consider what would have to be done if the structure of the original dictionary changes

Comment: I believe the problem of this user has been solved. Of course, new issues would require new solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the dictionary *in situ* then you could do this:

```
dict_ = {
    "trip_id": 19121027,
    "Latitude": "21.160284",
    "Longitude": "72.772457",
    "Speed": "46.00"
}

for k in 'Latitude', 'Longitude':
    if v := dict_.get(k):
        dict_.setdefault('Location', []).append(v)
        del dict_[k]

print(dict_)
```

If you want a new dictionary then:

```
new_dict = {}

for k, v in dict_.items():
    if k in {'Latitude', 'Longitude'}:
        new_dict.setdefault('Location', []).append(v)
    else:
        new_dict[k] = v
```

**Output:**

```
{'trip_id': 19121027, 'Speed': '46.00', 'Location': ['21.160284', '72.772457']}
```